# How can I get rid from the error in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, compiler-errors

How can I get rid from the error in Visual Studio? I am  very new to C++ and Visual Studio and I can not get what is wrong with my program. What I am trying to do is just to compile it.

Here it is:
[image]

Comment: It is an error, not an exception.

Comment: @manni66, changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is just to compile it.

In order to compile a single source file in Visual Studio, you can use the "Compile" item in the "Build" menu. The shortcut is CTRL+F7.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the error shows up! You don't have a main() function in your solution at all

Comment: How can I compile the `sqrt.cpp` without running it?

Comment: @Yaroslav Change the project type to library instead of executable.

Comment: Running is essentially building the application and launching it. In order to build, all errors must be rectified. If you just want to check syntax errors, you should Intellisense. And looking from the screenshot, you don't have any other errors

Comment: @catweazle-1964, how can I do that? I tried To change the application type
With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
Click the Application tab.
For a Visual Basic project, in the Application Type list, click the desired type. But it did not work out.

Comment: @SurajS, I do not want to run, I just want to compile the `sqrt.cpp`, but I do not know how to do that. There is no compile button in VS.

Comment: ctrl+F5 to compile without debugging . that is it, but I would like some visual button in VS.

Comment: still ctrl+F5 does not work. it gives the same error.

Comment: By compile you mean check-errors, link all libraries, but not run the executable, it&amp;#39;s the build button in the toolbar, however, project will only build if there are no errors, as @catweazle-1964 suggested, change the project build target to library, but I doubt if that&amp;#39;s what you want. Perhaps edit the question to indicate whether you want a exe or a library

Comment: @SurajS, yep. I do not want to change the project type. I want just to compile it. I tried to Build but it gives me errors even though as you can see on the screenshot everything is okay.

Comment: Will I be able to compile .cpp with main() function?

Comment: Then I&#39;m sorry it will not compile(build) unless all the errors are rectified, just put an empty main(). What is the purpose of you wanting to compile? Check errors?

Comment: @SurajS, I just learn OOP from the manual and it says to compile the file using VS without detailed explanation of how to do it.

Comment: Well, I don't know your real motives but you might as well use a main() function.

Comment: @Yaroslav: Of course there's a compile button. Open the "Build" menu and you'll find the "Compile" item in it, probably as the last item. As you will also see, the correct shortcut to compile a single *.cpp file is CTRL+F7.

Comment: @Yaroslav: You're welcome. I've turned the comment into an answer.